# Objective-C macro in preprocessor IF

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, boolean, c-preprocessor

I have a project with some macros that are defined using Objective-C statements, like this:

```
#define TEST [someObject someNumber] == 500
```

I need to define another value based on this result, like this:

```
#if TEST
  #define THING = 1
#else
  #define THING = 2
#endif
```

But, this doesn't work. And I can't use `#ifdef TEST` because the value is always defined. Even if it's `false`, it's still defined.

`TEST` is based on an ObjC statement, and it seems like the preprocessor has no way of evaluating it. So, is there no way to test for this?

Comment: Can the preprocessor know the value of `[someObject someNumber]` at runtime?

Comment: Can the preprocessor know the value of [someObject someNumber] at buildtime?

Comment: Maybe. Once runtime starts, it should know the value. If it does, how would I know? And how would I use it?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think this is a dumb question. Since TEST must be evaluated during runtime, there's no way to know the value of it during build time. Because the preprocessor can't know the value, it can't test it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you wrote:

> Since TEST must be evaluated during runtime, there's no way to know the value of it during build time. Because the preprocessor can't know the value, it can't test it. Is this correct?

Yes.

The preprocessor runs (at least logically) *before* the rest of the compiler. It is essentially language and syntax agnostic, and does not even have access to constants defined in your code. The conditional constructs operate solely with preprocessor tokens.